# ASP.NET C# DataTables replace specific value in specific columns in Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a problem with checking the value of an specific Column in a DataTable.
My DataTable is coming from a sql query and it has in this case 8 columns.

My 3rd column is a column called Status. In the Database status is going to be saved as numbers. 1 = "open", 2 = "in work", 3 = "closed" .

Now I'm iterating my whole table until this column and I want to check whether the value is 1 2 or 3 and replace the 1 2 or 3 with the corresponding status name. (I'm iterating, because there will be more columns which are going to be modified, so not only the column 2 in every row, but also 4,5 - but they are going to be same way like column 2. So if I understand one, I can do the rest similar).

But I don't know how to check the value, I have tried the .contains and equals method.

Here is my code:

```
 //for each row
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
            //search colums
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j == 2)
                {
                    if (dt.Columns[j].Equals("1") == true)
                    {
                    // dt.Columns[j].value should be replaced with "open";
                    }

                    if (dt.Columns[j].Equals("2") == true)
                    {
                    // dt.Columns[j].value should be replaced with "in-work";
                    }

                    if (dt.Columns[j].value == "3")
                    {
                    // dt.Columns[j].value should be replaced with "closed";
                    }
                }
}
```

So how could I check the value of the Column and replace with a string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try checking with this:

```
if(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() == "1")
```

And replace with this:

```
dt.Rows[i][j] = "Open";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `dt.Columns[j]` is a `DataColumn` convert it to string:

```
dt.Columns[j].ToString()
```

and then you can do

```
dt.Columns[j].ToString() == "1"
```

To rename your column just use the property `Caption`

```
var col = dt.Columns[j];
col.Caption = "in-work";
```

Comment: This didn't worked for me, There were no modifications made, but I have tried like one answer below, and this is working. But nevertheless thank you :)